# How do I add a link to an operations dropdown menu in views?

Tags: views, commerce

I am using [Commerce Kickstart 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

There is a view that lists all of the orders.  On each order, there is a dropdown menu with the options of 'Quick Edit' 'Payment' and 'Delete'.  I want to add my own operation on that order to view just the list of line items plus some custom information in a view.

However, I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to add a link to this dropdown menu and then go to my view when it is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your hook_menu in your module to add an operation to the dropdown pulldown of commerce orders.

```
$items['admin/commerce/orders/%commerce_order/<your operation>'] = array(
    'title' => 'Your Title',
    'page callback' => 'your_callback_for_the_operation',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access callback' => 'your_access_callback',
    'access arguments' => array(3),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 30,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
);
```